# What are templates in C++ 2

Tags: c++, templates

Hello everybody could anyone explain to me the difference between class temlplate member functio return type of type T (parameterized type) and an object of the claas return type

```
template<class T>
class array
{
public:
     array(T tx): tObj(tx){}
     T getObj()const{return tObj;}
     array GETTOBJ()const;
private:
     T tObj;
}
```

I have confusion: what is the difference between the return value of the functions getObj() and the GETTOBJ()?????

Comment: First of all: What's _'C++ 2'_ ??

Comment: `T` is just a substitute for a type. If `T` happens to be anything but `A`, then the difference is clear. If it's `A`, they have the same return type.

Comment: @raindrop7 Your edit made it even worse!!

Comment: I'm sorry I just wanted to write array instead of A. so do you mean that both the functions will return the same return type when specialisation?

Comment: If so needed at all, you would need to write `array<T>` for any references to your template type!

Comment: thnx alot all my friends 4 helpin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got:

- an `array`
- which holds `tObj`

The `tObj`'s real value is given through the arrays' constructor, and the `array` remembers it.

The `getObj` method returns the `tObj`, the thing that `array` remembered.

The `GETOBJ` method returns an `array`. It's code is not shown, but the difference is already here: it returns some `array`, not the thing the array remembers.

It's a difference like "returns a candy from a box" and "return the box".

Btw. I think that your sig is missing type parameter. I mean:

not: `array    GETTOBJ()const;`
but: `array<T> GETTOBJ()const;`

because array is a template, and `array` without type parameters is meaningless.

Comment: for example if we instantiate it like this: array<int> arInt(7);      what is then the return value of the two functons getObj() and GETOBJ()????

Comment: Please ignore my previous (deleted) comment. Too late and not enough sleep.

Comment: @raindrop7 It's simple substitution. `getObj()` returns and `int`, and `GETOBJ` returns an `array<int>`.

Comment: ok I got it thnx 2 u. but could u be a bit accurate in returns an "array<int>"? and what is the point in doing so return array<int>???

Comment: uh.. but we have just explained it..? what exactly do you not understand? do you understand the difference between returning "the box" and "the contents of the box"?

Comment: @raindrop7 Just grab a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: ok guys thnk you I got it. the examp0le of the box is so useful many thnx

Answer (score 0):

In the folowing example "class T" is not defined so, then when initializing this class, you can add as parameters what ever you what. For example:

```
array <int> _array_var(); //OR
array <char> _array_var(); // OR WHAT TYPE YOU WHANT, EVEN SOME STRUCTURES OR CLASSES
```

in your example "T tOBJ()" will return something of the type you initialized. For example:

if you

```
array <int> _array_var(); // THAN T=int.... SO T tOBJ will return int type, equivalent to

int tOBJ();
```

and so on... class T = typename T

for more info check:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)

ow yeah... and GETTOBJ returnes type of the class... always... 
the can be equal GETTOBJ with tOBJ in case you define:

```
array <array> _array_var();
```